# What does it mean to mount a file system in linux?

Tags: linux, file, filesystems, mount

I was reading somewhere that **File systems are ‘mounted’ over a particular directory**

Then there was an example of a user space file system saying that to mount you have to type 
`./program.py ~/somedir`

Can someone please explain the idea of mounting a filesystem in linux?

Answer (score 16):

A better way to describe "mount" is "attach".

The filesystem being mounted is attached to an empty directory of the existing filesystem. That is, the top level directory of the mounted filesystem becomes the directory on the existing filesystem.

Subdirectories of the mounted filesystem become the subdirectories of the former directory on the existing filesystem, and so on.

(The directory that was mounted on doesn't really have to be empty, but after mounting any contents it had are inaccessible, until the filesystem is unmounted).

Comment: Great explanation. Paints a clear picture in my mind; finally!

Answer (score 10):

Unlike on Windows where different file systems have different drive letters like `C:` and `D:`, Unix-like filesystems have a single root at `/`.  So when you attach a new disk drive or USB stick to a Linux system, the new filesystem has to exist somewhere in the existing filesystem.  In other words, some existing directory must serve as the root of the new filesystem.  These directories are known as mount points.

For removable drives, the mount points are usually located under `/media`, but they can be located anywhere.  Note that once a filesystem has been mounted over a directory, any files in that directory on the original filesystem are inaccessible until the new filesystem is unmounted.

Answer (score 5):

Mounting a filesystem simply means making the particular filesystem accessible at a certain point in the Linux directory tree. When mounting a filesystem it does not matter if the filesystem is a hard disk partition, CD-ROM, floppy, or USB storage device.

You can mount a file system with `mount` command. Normally `/mnt` folder is used for mounting.

**Example**

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
```